# Targeting the body which also has a class in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a body rage with the class fn-not-liked.

How can I target this in query, I've tried:

```
$('body .fb-not-liked').on('click', function(){

        console.log('hello');



    });
```

But no luck?

Comment: `'body.fb-not-liked'`?

Comment: Are you adding elements dynamically?

Comment: can you show us your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly targeting the body with a class. You want:

`$('body.fb-not-liked')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event delegation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.fb-not-liked', function () {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/WueDL/